# Accel Data Problems with Collecting and Plotting Accelerometer Data

Tags: object, plot, accelerometer, android-sensors

I copied code from this website: http://androidstream.wordpress.com/2013/01/16/android-collecting-and-plotting-accelerometer-data/ but it keeps displaying error messages

I specifically have a problem with this part of the code:

```
for (AccelData data : sensorData) {
            xSeries.add(data.getTimestamp() - t, data.getX());
            ySeries.add(data.getTimestamp() - t, data.getY());
            zSeries.add(data.getTimestamp() - t, data.getZ());
        }
```

I am relatively new to java and android, and I don't understand why after the AccelData data is added to sensorData under the onSensorChanged method, it shows up as type Object rather than type AccelData. Because of this, the following error also occurs:

```
        long t = sensorData.get(0).getTimestamp();
```

The contents of sensorData are no longer type AccelData and cannot use AccelData's methods.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the main class i.e. `public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener`,
OnClickListener { .... }
you have possibly forgotten to introduce sensorData as AccelData i.e.

```
private ArrayList <AccelData> sensorData;
```